# Can I get the selected files from an explorer window using powershell?

Tags: windows-explorer, powershell

In Applescript it's pretty easy to get the selected files in a Finder window.

```
tell application "Finder"
  set finderSelList to selection as alias list
end tell
```

Is there an equivalent in Powershell?

What I want to be able to do is get an arbitrary selection of files in an explorer window as an array of file objects. So

```
get-explorer-selection|%{do-something-to $_}
```

where `get-explorer-selection` returns an array of the selected files in the frontmost explorer window

Comment: Hmm, maybe I have to make the question clearer.

Comment: I see there's https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.multiselect?view=netframework-4.7.2 and as per https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2009/09/01/hey-scripting-guy-can-i-open-a-file-dialog-box-with-windows-powershell/ and that logic within the function that looks like this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32014711/how-do-you-call-windows-explorer-with-a-file-selected-from-powershell, you may be able to get those back in an array with some variation of logic like that using .Net within PowerShell basically right.

Comment: From a cursory glance, they all seem to be using the open file dialog, rather than an existing explorer window

Comment: Neither Windows or PowerShell provides any way of doing this, that I am aware of, outside of using what Pimp Juice IT pointed to.